# Using breeze-dark with non-KDE apps?

Tags: kde, gnome3, firefox, theme

TL;DR summary: is there a knowledge base anywhere for getting stuff like firefox to work well with breeze-dark?

The new light-on-dark KDE theme, breeze-dark, is great.  I love it.  However, some non-KDE apps work HORRIBLY with it, esp. when you enable the breeze-dark GTK theme.

I have

- Settings -> colors -> options -> apply colors to non-KDE4 applications enabled
- Settings -> Application Style -> Gnome Application Style (GTK):

  - GTK3 Theme: Default
  - Icon theme: Breeze Dark.

To enable breeze-dark for kde stuff in the first place:

- Settings->Application Style-> Widget Style: Breeze
- Settings->Workspace Theme -> Cursor Theme: Breeze
- Settings->Workspace Theme -> Desktop Theme: Breeze Dark
- Settings->Colors->Scheme->Breeze Dark

Some [tweaks to window titlebar color](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=285&t=126190) I like for breeze-dark.

Anyway, some web pages in FF end up with textboxes where you enter black text on a grey background.  I have https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/breeze-dark/.

I had to mess with eclipse to get it usable with breeze-dark (by picking a theme with http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/), but links still show dark blue on a gray background, which is very hard to read.

So the question: Is there a wiki or other kind of collection of tweaks / patches / stuff for non-KDE apps to make them usable with breeze-dark?  I like breeze-dark enough that I'm willing to spend time messing with some of the software I use, but I don't want to waste time solving problems other people have already solved.  And I could put stuff I figure out somewhere that others can benefit.

I unfortunately don't have the rep on this sub-site to create a new tag.  Can someone please add breeze-dark for me, and take out this paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need a GTK theme for the GTK apps to look like the KDE ones. For that there's an attempt being developed

https://github.com/dirruk1/gnome-breeze

and it already supports the Dark variation in the GTK3 version:

https://github.com/dirruk1/gnome-breeze/issues/2

Comment: Is a theme really all that's needed?  I think some apps may have colors that aren't theme-chosen, and those colors work poorly with a dark theme.  KDE's settings UI can already set a breeze-dark gtk3 theme.  I'll check it out, though, thanks.